# Authlogic does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a form which has the following 3 (username, password, email) fields. I would like to validate password and email as per authlogic. But I gonna validate username as per my wish.

**html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @author do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.text_field :password %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

**model.rb**

```
 acts_as_authentic                    //to validate (password and email fields)
 acts_as_authentic do |u|
   u.validate_username_field = false //avoid validating username field 
 end
```

This throws the following error.

```
undefined method `validate_username_field=' for #<Class:0x0000000443cc78>
```

What mistake I am doing here??

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for @author do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :username%>
  <%= f.text_field :username%>
  <%= f.label :password%>
  <%= f.text_field :password%>
  <%= f.label :email%>
  <%= f.text_field :email%>
```

<% end %>
acts_as_authentication                   //to validate (password and email fields)

`acts_as_authentic do |u|;`

u.validate_username_field = false //avoid validating username field 
 end

Comment: I cant understand what u would like to say. I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890652/an-authlogic-form-is-giving-me-incorrect-validation-errors-why